# jquery ui droppable elements close to each other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

i have a few droppable elements that are close to each other and i'm using `tolerance : 'touch'`. when a draggable element hover between two of them, the drop event fire twice.

see my example: https://jsfiddle.net/rcrurwt5/

any suggestion?

Comment: I would advise `tolerance: 'intersect'` versus `touch`. *"touch": Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.*

Answer (score 1):

`touch` seems a bit too greedy. I would advise `intersect`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rcrurwt5/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item').draggable({
     revert: true
   });
   $('.item_drop').droppable({
     hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
     tolerance: 'intersect',
     drop: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).css('background', 'orange');
     }
   });
 });
```

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance

Comment: @user2587454 When you use `touch`, it is working as designed. Meaning that any portion of the dragged object is 'touching' any part of the drop area. So all it takes is 1 pixel to overlap, and it will be triggered. So I am not sure what you want to fix.